# Change ASP.NET MVC site language based on url referrer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, localization, asp.net-identity, owin

I think I found a way (described below) to implement the following requested scenario, but I'll describe the complete context, in case I missed a simpler and/or cleaner solution to this issue.

## The context

I have a multi-culture site that uses the following: ASP.NET MVC 5, EF 6.1, ASP.NET Identity 2.2, SimpleInjector. It is hosted on Amazon EC2 with sql server on Amazon RDS, while the urls are registered with www.register.it. I implement external OAuth login through FB, Linkedin, Google and Paypal payments.

I need to have multiple url (www.url-en.com, www.url-it.com etc) all pointing to the same site and then change language and _layout (masterpage) according to the url typed by the user.

## The solution

Initially I thought about pointing all the urls to the ip of my site, but in this way I would need multiple ssl certificates configured (I don't even know if it's possible) and, more important, I wouldn't be able to manage callbacks from esternal login services and paypal payments.

So I configured redirection at the registrar level for each url to point to the main url (the english one), so I could read the HTTP_REFERRER variable in the global.asax Application_Start and set the culture cookie according to the referrer url. 
I've an ActionMethod in the Home controller that set the culture cookie (the same used also by the language selector on the site's pages) and then I have a custom RazorViewEngine that picks the localized view (if present).

The issue is that, having the app_pool in integrated mode, I can't read Request object in Application_Start, so I tried to do it inside the OWIN Configuration method, but HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer is null. Should I get the referrer from the OWIN context? How could I do that?
It'd be better/simpler to do that in javascript checking whether url and referrer are different?

Thanks
Matteo

Answer (score 1):

Why not detect the culture from the browser rather than using individual urls? Then based on the browser culture, you could tailor your urls to specific languages.

This would solve your multiple ssl issue, since you would only need one for the primary domain. It would also fix callback urls for payment gateways.

```
http://www.url.com/en-us/
http://www.url.com/es-es/
```

Comment: I tried to explain that to the customer, but unfortunately they want it in this way, with multiple urls and apparently there's no way to change their mind

Comment: ugh... customers who feel they know better are the best!!

Comment: I think it's more a marketing matter related to have a "localized" url